# Disable break point in a .class file

Tags: eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I have a problem with my Eclipse debugger. When I start my server (JBoss Server AS 4.2) it always stops in a break point in a class called WebAppClassLoader whose source code doesn't exist on my machine. I don't know how to disable that frustrating breakpoint. Any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 1):

Try Window/View/Other/Debug/Breakpoints

This will open a window that should list all the set breakpoints in your open project.  You can remove a breakpoint by unchecking it in the list.

Comment: This only shows breakpoints that are in source code. Is there some way to disable breakpoints that are coming from externally referenced jars? I'm not even sure how or why eclipse is picking up a break point from inside the jar...